# Tkinter Treeview shows only first 3 columns

Tags: python, tkinter

On startup of the program; Tkinter Treeview shows only the first 3 columns of 5. When you alter with the mousepointer in the heading the width of a random column by a small amount(few pixels), all columns comes in sight after releasing the mouse button.

update: option `displaycolumns="#all"` gives the same result.

```
hcolumns=('Hoofdstuk','Naam','Datum','Grootte','tafel')
tv=ttk.Treeview(mainframe, columns=hcolumns , show='headings', height=5)
for col in hcolumns:
    tv.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(tv, _col, False))
tv.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
```

Before altering width with mousepointer
[image]

After altering width with mousepointer:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding `width=<random number>` as column-option did the trick. So you get this:

```
for col in hcolumns:
    tv.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(tv, _col, False))
    tv.column(col, width=0)
```